# AWS organizations and Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I was using an AWS account with my credit card info and my personal account. Since I'm learning my way around AWS services I am using free tier as much as I can but I still have some small charges sent to my credit card at the end of the month. 
Recently I started a freelance project and they sent me a link and I became a part of the organization. Under My Organization I see the organization with the following note: "Organization features enabled... All features enabled...".
My question is how is billing done and if I spin up an instance not in the free tier who will pay for it and how can I manage and define who is paying for what?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Billing Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home) link in your console

If you can see details of your CC then it's you.

If you see something like this message:

[image: billing console no permissions]

Then it's managed by a different account that you do not even have permissions to see.

Comment: So isn't there a way to separate the billing, so I can continue my old instances and pay them myself and have a different bill for the organization?
Also what will happen if another organization invites me?

Comment: Not in a single AWS account.  
You can use only a single mode of payment per bill.  
See more details here:  
- https://aws.amazon.com/answers/account-management/aws-multi-account-billing-strategy/
However, you can use one billing AWS Account for managing multiple other AWS accounts, see here:  
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pay-aws-bill-multiple-payment-methods/